# How to import a zipped ".sas7bdat" file?

Tags: sas, zip

I have a **sas7bdat** format file, but it's zipped.

I could unzip the file and work on it, but this makes me lose hard disk space and time.

So I tried this code on SAS :

```
filename myfile ZIP 'C:\...\data.zip' member="data.sas7bdat" ;

data yoyo;
   infile myfile (data.sas7bdat);
   input; 
   put _infile_;
run;
```

But I get an empty yoyo table in the WORK library.

How can I successfully import the data.sas7bdat ?

Thank you,

Comment: Try `infile myfile(data)`

Comment: I tried; does not find the file at all. It says :
Physical file does not exist, data.

Comment: You cannot 'stream' a SAS dataset. You will have to uncompress the dataset either in session or ahead of time - both cases will require disk space. If you will be using this dataset several times, then you may just want to do uncompress it one time and write it out as gzip so that it can be streamed in.

Comment: Tell mgmt. that in the time it takes you to explore solutions your manhour costs could probably buy a 8TB disk. One unexplored possible way would be to send an external data set unzipping to a named pipe that impersonates a sas7bdat filename, such as `unzip myzippeddatasets.zip mydata.sas7bdat > \\.\pipe\unzip\mydata.sas7bdat`, and then attempting `SET "\\.\pipe\unzip\mydata.sas7bdat`.  data step might balk at a serial (i.e. pipe) set source.  You could also try using a TAPE libref to access the named pipe.

Answer (score 2):

You need to uncompress the dataset before SAS can use it.  So you need to find a place that has enough space for the fully expanded file.

Note that your code is trying to specify the member name of the file within the ZIP file twice.  You should only do that once. Either point the fileref to the aggregate location and use member name in the reference.  Or point the fileref to the individual member and just use the fileref.

Here is a method to expand the file into your current WORK folder.

```
%let member=data.sas7bdat;
filename in zip 'C:\...\data.zip' member="&member" recfm=n;
filename out "%sysfunc(pathname(work))/&member" recfm=n;
data _null_;
   rc=fcopy('in','out');
run;
```

You can now work with the file using the name WORK.DATA.

```
proc print data=work.data(obs=1); run;
```

If you want to read data from a ZIP file directly then it either needs to be raw (text) data or in a streaming format, like a SAS V5 XPORT file.